# How to get list of activities included in new ClearCase baseline from commandline?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

When making baseline manually, it shows the "Make Baseline" dialog with list of activities to include in new baseline.

How to get that list from commandline (from `cleartool` or other tool, in Windows and Linux)?

Answer (score 0):

The closest would be described in the technote "[Activities delivered since the last baseline](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21136012)"

> When working in a UCM project, it is often useful to determine the activities delivered to an integration stream since the last baseline was applied.
>   The [`cleartool diffbl`](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_diffbl.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-2-7&lang=en) command can accomplish this.
>   However, `cleartool diffbl` must be run against each modifiable component that the project uses.

The command syntax is:

```
cleartool diffbl -activities baseline:<baseline> stream:<integration_stream>
```

That means you must determine that latest most recent baseline of a component on a given stream first.

As mentioned by the OP [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406406/how-to-get-list-of-activities-included-in-new-clearcase-baseline-from-commandlin/31407555#comment50826288_31407555), the `diffbl` works with the *most recent baseline*:

- either the one listed first by `lsbl`
- or the foundation baseline if it is more recent.
  cleartool lsbl -stream integration_stream -component user1_comp@/vobstore/pvob

*Then* make the `diffbl` in order to list the activities which are candidate for the next baseline.

> The `cleartool lsbl -stream ... -component ...` seems to return the last baseline created in this stream.
>   But `cleartool diffbl -activities baseline:... stream:...` prints some useless junk **if that baseline is not last in stream** (this might happen if stream was rebased, and no new baseline was created since then; the last baseline becomes the foundation baseline).
>
> So `cleartool diffbl` needs foundation baseline if it's newer than last baseline created in the stream. In this case it correctly outputs list of activities.

Comment: The `cleartool lsbl -stream ... -component ...` seems to return the last baseline **created in this stream**. But `cleartool diffbl -activities baseline:... stream:...` prints some useless junk if that baseline **is not last in stream** (this might happen if stream was rebased, and no new baseline was created since then; the last baseline becomes the foundation baseline). So `cleartool diffbl` needs foundation baseline if it's newer than last baseline created in the stream. In this case it correctly outputs list of activities.

Comment: @my_stk_oflw_account yes, the method I mentioned is to be used with the most recent baseline. Either the one liste by lsbl or the foundation baseline indeed.

Comment: @my_stk_oflw_account I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.